# What is the difference between padding and bodyPadding

Tags: extjs

`Ext.panel.AbstractPanelView` class has `padding` and `bodyPadding` properties.

Seems like both acts the same.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bodyPadding

```
padding : Number/String
Specifies the padding for this component. The padding can be a single numeric value to apply     to all sides or it can be a CSS style specification for each style, for example: '10 5 3 10'.


bodyPadding : Number/String
A shortcut for setting a padding style on the body element. The value can either be a number to be applied to all sides, or a normal css string describing padding.
```

So the difference is to what element padding will be applied.

Comment: I saw that. So what is `body element`? What is the difference between `component` and `body element`?

Comment: One of them is applied to content of the panel and the other to the panel component itself. You can see the difference, when border and bodyBorder is set.